# How to mirror two screens / nvidia graphic pilot / LMDE / Macbook 2008

Tags: x11, nvidia, multi-monitor, display-settings

I'm using LMDE on a MacBook 2008; it works perfectly (and my MacBook runs much more faster than with Mac OS X)

I have one problem: when I plug in an external display, I can't get the two displays to display the same thing (mirror) — I always have two different screens.

When I go into the System Configuration Tool, and then Display Tools, I'm not able to choose the "same image on both screens" (I can't click it).

I'm also using the NVIDIA X Server tools, nothing like a mirror option in it — or perhaps, I don't understand how to switch it.

The graphics pilot I use is the nvidia-310 one — my graphics card is a GeForce 9400M.

Answer (score 1):

`xrandr --output DP-0 --auto --same-as LVDS-0`

You can use `xrandr` to change your display settings without much effort. Generally I find that it gives more options then GUI tools.

You will need to change DP-0 and LVDS-0 to match your display names. Those are mine from my MBP with the external monitor plugged in the display port.

Comment: Well, it works this way, thx :)
But I still know understand why the GUI doesn't allow me to have mirror displays - anyway